# Python Flask + threading

Tags: python, flask

Мира всем! Занялся я вот какой штукой, нужно на flask написать не большой сайт и интегрировать в него телеграмм бота. Для бота использую pyTelegramBotAPI. Как бы сложностей нет, делаем роут на hook и через хук слушаем update. Но это не удобно на этапе разработки, по этому я использую polling. Но вот не задача, как бы процесс 1 а демона 2, логично что демона polling-a нужно вешать на отдельный процесс. Я так и сделал, вот тут и возникла проблема. Polling хорошо вешается на отдельный процесс и все работает замечательно, но проблема в том что поток запускается 2 раза. Почему так происходит безусловно понятно:

```
import json

from flask import Flask
from flaskr.db import DataBase

app = Flask(__name__, subdomain_matching=True)

# Set config
app.config.from_file('settings.json', json.load)

# Connect database
app.db  = DataBase(app)

# Register context
with app.app_context():
    import flaskr.urls
    import flaskr.bot

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloaded=False)
```

И непосредственно бот:
import threading, time, json, math

```
from . import functions as func
from telebot import TeleBot, apihelper
from flask import current_app as app

# Get app variable
db, config  = app.db, app.config

apihelper.ENABLE_MIDDLEWARE = True

tg  = TeleBot(app.config['TG_TOKEN'], parse_mode="markdown")

# Bot polling 
def polling(): 
    while True:
        try:
            print(" * Bot start successful!")
            tg.stop_polling()
            tg.polling(none_stop=True)
        except Exception as ex: 
            print(" * Bot start error: %s" % ex)
            time.sleep(2)
        else:
            tg.stop_polling()
            break

# Starting polling process
proccess = threading.Thread(target=polling, daemon = True, name="botProccess")
proccess.start()
```

В итоге процесс polling-a запускается когда загружается в context и потом непосредственно при reloaded. как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Все решается отслеживанием reload. Зачем мне перезапускать polling с каждым reload-ом если сама функция полинга не меняется. То-есть нужно отслеживать старт программы и запускать процесс только при старте.

```
# Starting polling process
if 'WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN' not in os.environ:
    proccess = threading.Thread(target=polling, daemon = True, name="botProccess")
    proccess.start()
```